# how does this xpath behave?

Tags: xpath

```
html//p//table//tr//td//a
```

Would this xpath be able to handle any element appearing between the above said elements ?

for ex)

```
html/p/div/table/tr/td/a
html/span/p/div/div/table/tr/td/b/a
```

Comment: I'm not sure thats why I asked lol

Comment: Earlier you had put the xpath as "html//p//table//tr//td/a" now you have changed it to "html//p//table//tr//td//a" so people are downcasting my answer unnecessarily

Comment: well I was editing the question. don't get phased by downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `html//p//table//tr//td//a`
>
> Would this xpath be able to handle any
>   element appearing between the above
>   said elements ?
>
> for ex)
>
> `html/p/div/table/tr/td/a`
>
> `html/span/p/div/div/table/tr/td/b/a`

**Yes, in both cases.**

Comment: Earlier he had put the xpath as "html//p//table//tr//td/a" now you have changed it to "html//p//table//tr//td//a" so people are downcasting my answer unnecessarily

Comment: @Puspendu-Banerjee: I haven't edited the question and right now the question hasn't been edited at all. Also, it seems to me that the 2nd sentence of your answer is not true.

Comment: Would you mind to clarify, why the 2nd sentence doesn't seem correct?

Comment: Dimitre, would the xpath also be able to cover `html/table/tr/td/a` in this case the `p` is completely missing.

Comment: @heymona: No. Any node-test specified in the XPath expression must select at least one node.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, It will handle both of the scenarios**

Comment: @Puspendu-Banerjee: There is no need for the proposed XPath expression to be changed at all, in order to select the same nodes as the second XPath expression. You are saying that the XPath expression needs to be modified -- this is not true.

Comment: @Dimitre May be it's my mistake but as I can remember the XPath that he had given at very beginning was "html//p//table//tr//td/a". see the single "/" before "a". Then I answered and after that the XPath had been modified to "html//p//table//tr//td//a" and after that you have answered the question. You have answered 9 minutes after I had answered.

Comment: @Puspendu-Banerjee: I truly believe that this has been the case and it is good that you have corrected your answer, accordingly. The baffling thing is I don't see any indication the question was modified...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Edits by the same person [within the grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) are automatically merged (I guess to reduce noise in the history).

Comment: @Phrogz: OK, I see now. Because I know that when *I* edit my answer I can see the edits, and when someone else edits a question, this can also be seen. So, it is when the OP edits his question that this isn't shown.